# How can I make tableview the default view screen for my iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have created a single view project, but now I would like the default view when you first open the app to be the tableview controller.  Can I delete the original view that I no longer want? Or disable it somehow?

Additional info: using storyboard in Xcode 5.0.2

Solution:
I simply dragged the arrow in storyboard to the table view controller instead.  Thanks everyone for your help!  I'm brand new to this.  :)

Comment: Please give us more information, ios version, XIB, storyboard etc.

Comment: Additional info: using storyboard in Xcode 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Storyboard , You can set the default startup view in StoryBoard easily.

Comment: That would the ideal solution, how do I do this?  Sorry if this is an obvious question, I'm brand new to this and couldn't find the info in my searches.  Thanks!

Comment: I just figured it out - drag the arrow in storyboard to the table view controller.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

no need to delete the view. Add a UITableview over the UIView. And set the tableview frame to full screen.

Answer (score 0):

No need to disable it.

1. Go to the `Document outline`, select `View Controller`
2. Remove the view under `UIViewController`.
3. Go to `Identity Inspector`, change `Custom Class` to `UITableViewController`.

Note that the controller in storyboard has now a text `Table View Controller` on it.

I would suggest to create a custom class inherited by UITableViewController and set `Custom Class` in inspector to your custom tableview controller.

Hope it helps!

[image]